# Push notifications on iOS - Which architecture?

Tags: ios, push-notification, appcelerator

I've successfully implemented push notifications on Android devices using: GCM, ti.goosh and HTTP cURL POSTs. What similar options are there for iOS?

Do you suggest Appcelerator Mobile Backend Services? https://onesignal.com ? Any other Ti module?

Thanks

Comment: u can alse use firebase push notifications service.

Comment: GCM is also there for iOS, but you should be probably use Firebase instead as notification service

Comment: Google is deprecating GCM and moving on to Firebase. You might want to invest in that. It works with both Android and iOS

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions to move to Firebase. How can I use Firebase with iOS and Appcelerator? This is the question! :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have had poor experience with Appcelerator's push service.  I don't think that Appcelerator is focused enough on push notifications specifically.  On numerous occasions, their platform would mysteriously underdeliver (maybe getting to only 30% of our audience), and getting diagnostics on these events was like pulling teeth (like a week of back-and-forth with their support team to get them to investigate the problem).  They never really provided much guidance in terms of best practices for client-side integration of their SDK.

We recently moved to Pushwoosh, and have been much happier with their platform.  They are extremely knowledgeable on all things push-related, and they have given us an impressive amount of support in our questions about arcane topics like push tokens, ios do-not-disturb mode, android background services, using multiple push providers, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jason, I'll consider Pushwoosh!